# Leaflet JS not displaying map properly

Tags: leaflet, tiles, tile-map-service

I am trying to render a map provided by a tile map service based on {x}, {y} and {z} using leaflet.js. So far, I managed to render the map, but it is isn't shown correctly. The tiles are repeated oddly, and the Lat and Lng aren't accurate.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzncwy9r/8/)

For example, Lat: -2.6000285, Lng: 118.015776 with a zoom level of 5 should get the map to show the country Indonesia ([see coords at google maps](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/2%C2%B036'00.0%22S+118%C2%B000'56.8%22E/@-2.7416254,117.8633477,8z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-2.6!4d118.015776))

But it is not the case in my jsfiddle. Instead, Indonesia can be found around
Lat: 66, Lng: 331, Lat: 66, Lng: -29, and probably at other points every 360 increment/decrement as well. The point is, the lat-lng is not accurate to real world map.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Tile Map service uses a zoom offset of 1, i.e. the entire world fits in 4 tiles when `{z}` value is `2` (unfortunately your service does not provide the tile at zoom 1 where the entire world would have fit a single tile).

Tile showing 1/4 of the world with X = 0, Y = 0 and Z = 2:

[image: To left quarter world tile]

Usually the entire world fits in 4 tiles when `{z}` value is `1`.

Therefore you can use that service with Leaflet Tile Layer and specifying [`zoomOffset`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer-zoomoffset) option with value `1`:

```js
L.tileLayer(url, {
    zoomOffset: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzncwy9r/9/

Comment: Whoa, thank you! That is exactly what was wrong with it!